Unable to save changes because of circular dependency
I encountered a problem in an ASP.NET Core application using EF Core with a SQL Server database. In the application, project entities are stored in a table named TProjects. Another table, TProjectSteps, allows steps to be assigned to projects via a foreign key relationship. Each step includes a step number, which must be unique within a project.
The problem occurs when attempting to modify and reorder steps in the application. In the backend code using EF Core, I've implemented an algorithm within the update endpoint of a project step to detect changes in step numbers. If a step number changes, the step numbers of other steps within the same project are adjusted accordingly.
For instance, if a project has steps numbered 1 through 5, and the user modifies step 1 to have a step number of 5, steps 2 through 5 are decremented by 1.
To prevent invalid scenarios where multiple steps share the same number within a project, a unique constraint was added to the database.
However, since implementing this unique constraint, I've encountered difficulties saving changes that result in the reordering of step numbers. For example, if I attempt to swap steps 9 and 10 in a project with 10 steps, calling SaveChangesAsync() after making these changes throws the following exception:

Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in
the data to be saved.

It seems like EF Core cannot apply these changes because it cannot determine the order in which they should be applied. Unfortunately, I am not exactly sure how to solve this.
Is there any elegant way to solve this problem without resorting to temporarily assigning unused step numbers to avoid circular dependencies?

Is there anything what references the steps? IF yes, there might be one of them referencing the projects too (hence circular). To resolve the unique issue, an option would be to delete all the steps and re-insert them with the new IDs or alternatively change the unique to not include NULLs (filtered index), update all steps to NULL first then update them with the new values. Disclaimer: this is a comment, not an answer because I am not using EF/EFCore and thus can't provide details on implementation.

@Pred But this would essentially turn the update endpoint into a "delete everything and re-create it with the new step numbers" endpoint, right? I was hoping that there would be a more elegant way to solve this, but so far I can't seem to find one.

Yes, it would, except not to delete everything, but only the ones which are on the projects which have changed. If you want to keep the integrity of the data, you'll either need to update all records at once (e.g. from a temp table with a join) or have an intermediate state which is known to be not correct, or a very specific order of updates, ensuring that the row-by-row updates never cause duplications. Alternatively you can remove the unique, do the updates, then enforce it again, but this in my head is similar to have no integrity. All can be done in a transaction so you can handle errors.

With limited information, I would say that you can remove the foreign key of the step to see if it resolves the issue. Another approach is when ever the steps are chaged then you can delete all the steps and reinsert with new step sequence.
You can refer to this one to see if it helps.

Thanks for the response! I am not sure why removing the foreign key would resolve this issue. I already know that the circular dependency exception is only thrown when the unique constraint exists, so the foreign key does not cause this issue as far as I can tell. The foreign key works by storing the ID of the corresponding project in a column inside the project step table, so it has no connection to the step number.
